# How to output a group, based on the same column cell, while looping it out into html?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I want to create groups while looping all my rows from a database table.

example database:

```
id | sex | name | age
1 | male | kevin | 20
2 | male | bob | 24
3 | female | jenny | 24
4 | female | bob | 20
5 | no | gaben | 13
```

I want to group the entries by names.
The output i'm looking for is something like this:

Should output:

```
<div id="bob">
 <a>bob male 24</a>
 <a>bob female 20</a>
</div>
<div id="kevin">
 <a>kevin male 20</a>
</div>
<div id="gaben">
 <a>gaben no 13</a>
</div>
<div id="jenny">
 <a>jenny female 24</a>
</div>
```

I was making two while loops inside of eachother. It only outputs one `<div>` for one `name`. Each div should be created for each unique `name`. So when someone has the same `name`, they should be put together into the same `<div id="name">` element/group;

I created a `names[]` array, so i could check if the name is inside the names array. If not, it should create a `<div id="name">` element. After the `<div id="name">` element/group was created, the inner loop should loop all the `$name = $row['name']` inside that div element. If the loop was finished, the div should be closed `</div>` and the name added into the `$names[] = $name` array. So it wouldn't create the same `div` again. Then it should continue with the next name, but it somehow doesn't do that.

```
<?php
if($resultCheck > 0){

    $names = [];

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $name = $row['name'];

        if(!in_array($fieldset, $fieldsets)){
            echo '<div name="'.$hersteller.'">';
        }

        while($names = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<a>'.$row['name'].' '.$row['sex'].' '.$row['age'].'</a>';
        }

    }

    if(!in_array($name, $names)){
        echo '</div>';
    }

    $names[] = $name;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution won't work unless you use `GROUP BY name` in your query. So in case you are not using `GROUP BY` then solution would be like this:

```
<?php
if($resultCheck > 0){
    $names = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $names[$row['name']][] = array($row['name'], $row['sex'], $row['age']);
    }

    foreach($names as $name => $details){
        echo '<div name="'.$name.'">';
        foreach($details as $d){
            echo '<a>'.$d['name'].' '.$d['sex'].' '.$d['age'].'</a>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

And in case you are using `GROUP BY name` in your query, then your result set would be grouped by name and you could use a solution like below:

```
<?php
if($resultCheck > 0){
    $names = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if(!in_array($row['name'], $names)){
            if(empty($names)){
                echo '<div name="'.$name.'">';
            }else{
                echo '</div'>;
                echo '<div name="'.$name.'">';
            }
            echo '<a>'.$row['name'].' '.$row['sex'].' '.$row['age'].'</a>';
            $names = $row['name'];
        }else{
            echo '<a>'.$row['name'].' '.$row['sex'].' '.$row['age'].'</a>';
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the difference between using `GROUP BY` and without? The first example looks more logic to me and less code if i'm not wrong.

Comment: @DamianToczek As I said in my answer, `GROUP BY name` will group your result set in the chronological order of names. So in that case, second solution snippet should work fine for you.

Comment: I was trying to find something about `$names[$row['name']][] = array()` It's bit complicated to understand what's going on there. I know that arrays are made like this `$myArray = ['name','age']` etc, but i don't understand what this `$names[][] = array()` is. Could you tell me why you have `[][]` next to the variable name ?

Comment: @DamianToczek `$array[][]` is for array of arrays i.e. multidimensional array. Read more on this [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=multidimensional+array+php&oq=multidimensional+array+php&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3j0l2.1746j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @DamianToczek Please explain *it doesn't work*, are you getting any error? Your current vs. expected result?